# Cannot connect to home wifi network on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, internet

Im having a problem where my lenovo e480 cannot connect to my home network, but can connect to my mobile hotspot.
Any points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. What further information can I provide in order to make solving the issue easier?

Thanks.

Comment: does it say authentication error or something else? and try playing with the command ```nm-connection-editor``` and see if you find anything strange

Comment: no, just says connection error

Comment: @Zawszy did you figure this out.
I am facing the same problem after updating to Ubuntu 20.04.
The problem began midway during the update and persisted after restarting.
I have even tried 1. changing the MAC address of my WiFi card, 2. disabling secure boot, 3. Hard resetting the WiFI router